# How to remove/replace tabBar items in UITabbarController subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I don't see how why I get an error `thread 1 breakpoint 1.1` on this line :

`self.tabBar.setItems(items, animated: false)`

I try to replace the current items in my tabbar with custom buttons.

Here is the code :

```
class MyTabController : UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width*0.3, self.view.frame.height))
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1Clic", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        /*
        let items = NSMutableArray(array: self.tabBar.items!)
        items.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
        */
        let array = [button1]
        let items = NSMutableArray(array: array)
        self.tabBar.setItems(items, animated: false) //HERE

        /*
        //in objective-c
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBar.items];
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self.tabBar setItems:items];
        */

        self.tabBar.addSubview(button1)
    }

    func button1Clic() {
        println("1 clic")
    }
}
```

---

EDIT :
This is not working, I get the same error as before :

```
let tab1 = UITabBarItem(title: "test", image: UIImage(named:"food3.png"), tag: 0)
self.tabBar.setItems([tab1], animated: false)
```

About the buttons, they are correctly added to the tabBar, but it is placed above the other items? Is there a way to replace the uitabbarItem by the buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling `self.tabBar.setItems` with a UIButton array. It should be called with a UITabBarItem array.

```
let barItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Featured, tag: 0)
self.tabBar.setItems([barItem], animated: false)
```

If you want a UIButton on a tab bar, just call addSubview as you wrote:

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width*0.3, self.view.frame.height))
button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1Clic", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.tabBar.addSubview(button1)
```

Comment: Thanks Yoichi, it is not working, I edited my post, could you have a look? Thanks

Comment: I made a library to place a UIButton on a tab bar. It's written in Objective-C, but probably you can use it from Swift too. If the library itself doesn't fit in your project, try writing your code similar to the Objective-C code. https://github.com/yoichitgy/EEToolbarCenterButton